# Angular/JS approach to addEventListener for "loginCompleted"?

Tags: microsoft-graph-toolkit

I am trying to tailor a series of events based on what happens when the mgt-login component throws the "loginCompleted" event.

So far I have not been able to implement an eventListener which will hear the "loginCompleted" event.

I have tried the below javascript inside of the index.html

```
        let mgtlogin = document.querySelector('mgt-login');
        mgtlogin.addEventListener('loginCompleted', (e) => {
        alert ("loginCompleted");
        document.getElementById("clickMe").click(); )}
```

Answer (score 1):

This event is supported for the `mgt-login` control however, there appears to be a slight syntax error in your code above. The following code works for me:

```
  let mgtlogin = document.querySelector('mgt-login');
  mgtlogin.addEventListener('loginCompleted', e => {
    alert('loginCompleted');
    document.getElementById('clickMe').click();
  });
```

in this case the `)` is completed too early.

If this isn't the issue, can you please provide more information pertaining the specific error you are getting?